# How can I allow Easeljs Tickers to remain active when a user switches tabs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, requestanimationframe

I am making a game using Createjs and I have a problem with the game pausing automatically once I switch tabs. I have researched on this topic and I believe to have found out that it isn't Createjs pausing the Tickers but the browsers themselves. This has something to do with the Page Visibility API which knows when the document is hidden or visible and once hidden, I believe it slows down the RAF or setIntervals of that document which makes it seem that it is paused. This provides help to the CPU and Battery so they don't burn out.

I need my game to always keep running in the background even if the user switches tabs. What is the best way I can do this? Just want to mention that I am using Easeljs with the Tickers if that matters.

Please correct me if I was wrong with anything I said. I am still a beginner and by correcting me, I will be able to understand the real problem. Thank you for your  time.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are describing is expected, the browser will throttle JavaScript execution to about 1 FPS.

The usual approach to get around this is to make sure your application/animations are not tied to a specific FPS. For example, here is a sample where a shape moves across the screen: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/4neobe00/2/

- It takes about 5 seconds to go from the left to the right
- A count shows how many times it resets

If you just add a certain amount to the sprite (such as the blue shape), it will only get updated 1 time per second when the browser frame is closed. I used 1.66 because it closely matched the speed of the other sprite.

```
lockedShape.x = (lockedShape.x + 1.66); // Moves a certain amount per tick
```

However the Ticker provides a `delta` in the tick event, which will be around 1 when you have a reliable framerate, but provide a multiplier you can use to determine how long the frame takes. In the sample, an index is incremented by `1 x event.delta`:

```
index += event.delta;
```

Then the position is determined based on the index:

```
shape.x = (index/10)%500; // divide by 10 to slow it down, modulus 500 to make it loop
```

We can even determine how many times the item has "looped" because we know that the if you divide that index by the width, it will give you the number of loops:

```
text.text = (index/10/500 |0).toString(); // rough position divided by 500, rounded.
```

So using this approach, you can make the rest of your content run at a consistent speed, since you know how much time has elapsed since the last tick. Here is an [official tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Animation%20and%20Ticker/timeBased.html) (which has a sample that does basically the same thing, which is what was probably in my head when I made my own example).

Note that TweenJS uses time-based tweens, and you can set framerates on MovieClips and Sprites in EaselJS, which uses this approach.

Hope that helps.